# Maven causes internet connection to crash

Tags: java, windows, maven, crash

I'm using Maven 3.1.1 and M2Eclipse with Windows 8.1 64bit and Java 7 64bit
M2Eclipse always crashes with the following error:

```
    Errors occurred during the build.
    Error instantiating builder 'org.hibernate.eclipse.console.hibernateBuilder'.
    Plug-in org.hibernate.eclipse.console was unable to load class      org.hibernate.eclipse.builder.HibernateBuilder.
    An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.hibernate.eclipse.console   (824).
    Plug-in org.hibernate.eclipse.console was unable to load class org.hibernate.eclipse.builder.HibernateBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.hibernate.eclipse.console (824).
    Errors running builder 'CDI (Context and Dependency Injection) Builder' on project 'dagobert'.
    org/hibernate/eclipse/nature/HibernateNature
    Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'dagobert'.
    Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources- plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact  descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
    Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies  could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
    Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
    Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
```

If I run Maven-Update with forcing to update releases and snapshots Maven crashes with a timeout exception. With this error, my internet connection crashed. I can run ping google.de for instance, but no program has any connection. I have to reboot my machine.

If I run mvn -U clean install I get another error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project dagobert-engine: Compilation fa
ilure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\src\test\java\xxxxxxxxxx\test\util\Abs
tractTest.java:[18,40] error: package org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api does not
 exist
[ERROR] C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\src\test\java\xxxxxxxxxx\test\util\Abs
tractTest.java:[19,46] error: package org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven do
es not exist
[ERROR] C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\src\test\java\xxxxxxxxxx\test\util\Abs
tractTest.java:[18,40] error: package org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api does not
 exist
[ERROR] C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\src\test\java\xxxxxxxxxx\test\util\Abs
tractTest.java:[19,46] error: package org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven do
es not exist
[ERROR] C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\src\test\java\xxxxxxxxxx\test\util\Abs
tractTest.java:[49,30] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class MavenDependencyResolver
[ERROR] location: class AbstractTest
[ERROR] C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\src\test\java\xxxxxxxxxx\test\util\Abs
tractTest.java:[49,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

mvn -v:

```
C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 17:22:2
2+0200)
Maven home: C:\Software\maven
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Software\java\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: Does the compiling etc. work on the command line? Which Eclipse version are you using? M2E Version? Can you show the full pom file? (May be a reference to github project or something similar?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

Removed Avira Anti Virus and Windows Defender. Both applications blocked maven for no reason. I was also not able to add it to any whitelist.

Advise for next time: Don't use Windows, use Linux or Unix.